# Javascript Capitalize

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string something like "JOHN SMITH lives in Europe." and I'm trying to make it as "John Smith lives in Europe." i.e. the first name and last name has to be capitalized. Here is my code

```js
var str1 = "JOHN SMITH is an good person."
var str2 = str1.toLowerCase();
var str3 = [...str2];
var str4 = str3.slice(0, 2);
var str5 = str4.map(item => {
  item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
})
var str6 = [str5, str2]
console.log(str6)
```

Comment: What's the criterion exactly? Words in ALL CAPS must become Title Cased? Where to draw the line? Could you accidentally Title Case something like Usa too? Any other criterion?

Comment: Capitalizing nouns properly requires information in code to determine what IS a proper noun.  Also if the strings are static, then why not just do it yourself?  If you have a proper noun always accessible, you can easily lowercase everything real quick with a simple function.

I dont think you have enough information to clarify WHAT you are doing and how you would want it resolved.

Comment: @deceze based on his code he is trying to capitalize only the first two words

Comment: @Jonas That is an assumption based on a sample size of 1, which isn't enough to generalise into code for my taste. ;)

Comment: How are you throwing `JOHN SMITH` into `str1` to begin with? If it's a user input, I would suggest fixing the `firstName` and `lastName` before using/saving it. Otherwise you are now having to make code to support other code. Just fix it from the start.

Comment: @deceze seems my assumption was correct ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically going into the right durection, you just should use proper variable names and may use a small helper for capitalization:

```js
const capitalize = word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();

const capitalizeSentence = sentence =>
  sentence.split(" ").map((word, pos) => pos < 2 ? capitalize(word) : word).join(" ");

console.log(capitalizeSentence(
  "JOHN SMITH is an good person."
));
console.log(capitalizeSentence(
  "JOHN SMITH lives in Europe."
));
```

Some notes on your code:

`[...str2]` will give you an array of characters, it seems you want to get an array of words which you get with `str2.split(" ")`. To join two strings `[str5, str2]` won't work, rather do `str5 + " " + str2` but as `str5` is an array you would have to join it `str5.concat(str2).join(" ")`. And finally you have to `return` something from the mapper, then the code works as expected :)